# HTML Not displaying when DIV's are a different order to Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a AJAX timer That uses the `GET` command to retrieve a `JSON` encoded `MySQL` query via `PHP`...

The timer is working correctly & the information is also being retrieved...

To be able to store the results so that i can display them in `DIV` I have made a `VAR` called `LIST` and `EVALUATED` the `xmlhttp.responseText`

Then I have created a list of `documentgetelementbyid` to hold the results so they can be used in the DIV's around the site

Everything works perfectly if I display the data **in order** within HTML, but as soon as I attempt to display the data **not to the order in my JavaScript file** the display goes blank..

Im guessing that it is because of the way i am attempting to store the results within JavaScript..

How is it possible to store these results within JavaScript and then call them in HTML but not to the order they are within JavaScript..

I hope what I have explained makes sense, any advice would be greatly appreciated...

THE JAVASCRIPT CODE:

```
function getPlaylist()
{
     var xmlhttp, timer;

     if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
     {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
     } 
     else
     {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
     }

     xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function ()
     {
       if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) 
       {

          var list = eval ('('+xmlhttp.responseText+')');

          document.getElementById("list0.artist").innerHTML=list[0].artist;
          document.getElementById("list0.title").innerHTML=list[0].title;
          document.getElementById("list0.label").innerHTML=list[0].label;
          document.getElementById("list0.albumyear").innerHTML=list[0].albumyear;
          document.getElementById("list0.picture").innerHTML='<img src="/testsite/covers/' + list[0].picture + '" width="200" height="auto"/>';

          document.getElementById("list1.artist").innerHTML=list[1].artist;
          document.getElementById("list1.title").innerHTML=list[1].title;
          document.getElementById("list1.label").innerHTML=list[1].label;
          document.getElementById("list1.albumyear").innerHTML=list[1].albumyear;
          document.getElementById("list1.picture").innerHTML='<img src="/testsite/covers/' + list[1].picture + '" width="150" height="auto"/>';

          document.getElementById("list2.artist").innerHTML=list[2].artist;
          document.getElementById("list2.title").innerHTML=list[2].title;
          document.getElementById("list2.label").innerHTML=list[2].label;
          document.getElementById("list2.albumyear").innerHTML=list[2].albumyear;
          document.getElementById("list2.picture").innerHTML='<img src="/testsite/covers/' + list[2].picture + '" width="50" height="auto"/>';

          document.getElementById("list3.artist").innerHTML=list[3].artist;
          document.getElementById("list3.title").innerHTML=list[3].title;
          document.getElementById("list3.label").innerHTML=list[3].label;
          document.getElementById("list3.albumyear").innerHTML=list[3].albumyear;
          document.getElementById("list3.picture").innerHTML='<img src="/testsite/covers/' + list[1].picture + '" width="50" height="auto"/>';

          document.getElementById("list4.artist").innerHTML=list[4].artist;
          document.getElementById("list4.title").innerHTML=list[4].title;
          document.getElementById("list4.label").innerHTML=list[4].label;
          document.getElementById("list4.albumyear").innerHTML=list[4].albumyear;
          document.getElementById("list4.picture").innerHTML='<img src="/testsite/covers/' + list[4].picture + '" width="50" height="auto"/>';  
       }
    };


    xmlhttp.onerror = function() 
    {
      clearTimeout(timer);
    };

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "playlist.php?t=" + Math.random(), true);
    xmlhttp.send();


    timer = setTimeout(getPlaylist, 1000);
}
```

THE HTML CODE:

**(This works in the order below but if i were to change the first DIV to look for "list1.artist" instead of "list0.artist" the page will not display.)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="/testsite/OneSecondPlaylist.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="getPlaylist()">

<h1>Now Playing</h1>
<div id="list0.artist"></div>
<div id="list0.title"></div>
<div id="list0.label"></div>
<div id="list0.albumyear"></div>
<div id="list0.picture"></div>

<h2>Last Played</h2>
<div id="list1.artist"></div>
<div id="list1.title"></div>
<div id="list1.label"></div>
<div id="list1.albumyear"></div>
<div id="list1.picture"></div>

<h2>History</h2>
<div id="list2.artist"></div>
<div id="list2.title"></div>
<div id="list2.label"></div>
<div id="list2.albumyear"></div>
<div id="list2.picture"></div>

<div id="list3.artist"></div>
<div id="list3.title"></div>
<div id="list3.label"></div>
<div id="list3.albumyear"></div>
<div id="list3.picture"></div>

<div id="list4.artist"></div>
<div id="list4.title"></div>
<div id="list4.label"></div>
<div id="list4.albumyear"></div>
<div id="list4.picture"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you give an example of how you are changing the order?

Comment: @smitt04 for example if i were to display <div id="list1.artist"></div> in the NOW PLAYING part of the site instead of <div id="list0.artist"></div> ... the screen will no longer display

.... Do i need to loop throught the results in Javascript?

Comment: That shouldn't be the problem, you should be able to move the html around without affecting the javascript.

Comment: @smitt04 fettereddingoskidney answer below seems to be the reason for the break in the script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are doing something like this:

```
<h1>Now Playing</h1>
<div id="list1.artist"></div>
<div id="list1.title"></div>
<div id="list1.label"></div>
<div id="list1.albumyear"></div>
<div id="list1.picture"></div>

<h2>Last Played</h2>
<div id="list1.artist"></div>
<div id="list1.title"></div>
<div id="list1.label"></div>
<div id="list1.albumyear"></div>
<div id="list1.picture"></div>
```

?

If so, your screen is going blank because when you try to access the div with id="list1.artist", javascript finds two instances of the element with that id and throws an error. Because of this error, javascript aborts the remainder of the code where you are inserting the values into the divs using .innerHTML.

Open up your javascript console: right-click > Inspect Element > Console, and check to see whether you are getting a javascript error. This is likely your problem.

To answer your question about how to display the HTML in a different order...one implementation is to use knockout.js, which is an awesome data-binding library that makes doing things like this a snap (trust me, trust me, trust me). It'll take a little learning, but they have a great tutorial, and if you've never used it, it will successfully blow your mind :]

http://knockoutjs.com/

Good luck friendo.

Comment: I don't think I have ever seen javascript complain about multiple divs with the same ID, the javascript should just return the first element it finds with that id

Comment: @fettereddingoskidney that is exactly what is wrong... Thank you for explaining this...
When i make NOW PLAYING list0.artist & LAST PLAYED list0.artist i get "TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null" and it points to "document.getElementById("list1.artist").innerHTML=list[1].artist;" in the code